# VB.NET adjust auto generated code when implementing interface

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, namespaces, code-generation

When pressing enter after `Implements IInterface` Visual Studio generates the code for implementing all methods, properties etc. So far, so good... My 'problem' is that it inserts too much code:

```
Public Class A
    Implements IList(Of String)

    Public Sub Add(item As String) Implements System.Collections.Generic.ICollection(Of String).Add

    End Sub

    ...

End Class
```

I would like VS to realise that I have an `Import System.Collections.Generic` at the top of the file and that it can thus ommit the namespaces.

In the above example, `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection(Of String).Add` should only be 
 `ICollection(Of String).Add`.

How can this behavior be achieved?

**Update: What have you tried?**
Nothing. I have no idea where to start looking and all my google searches come up empty.

Comment: Good question. I actually thought that VS2010 had finally implemented smarter lookup. If that’s not the case you’re out of luck: there is no way to make it work, besides upgrading to the latest version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Changing the behavior will be available in VS 2012? Or VS 2012 will only do smarter lookup? Because I'd like to format the method parameters once they exceed X characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Roslyn preview (available at http://roslyn.codeplex.com) I believe that it should either be smart enough to not include the extra namespace information, or immediately bring up a QuickFix option to remove all instances of the extraneous code.